# Code Blocks how to hide plus and minus buttons

Tags: codeblocks

I'm talking about the - and + buttons that are in a white square box before every { , and when you click them they collapse and expand the code within the {} brackets. I pressed something on my keyboard and they suddenly appeared, I don't remember what though, now I can't find out how to make them disappear, there must be a way?

Comment: That is called code folding, see if you have options like that in your editor or ide settings

Comment: Ok I removed the buttons from the folding settings, now how do I make the vertical green line appear again, the one that was on the place of the - and + buttons? Codeblocks just doesn't feel the same without this green line

Comment: I have no experience in Codeblocks.